# CLLocationManager set speed of updates

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I am using `CLLocationManager` to get the user's X/Y cords. The delegate fires every second or so, but I only need the manager every 15 seconds or so to feed my API. Is there any way to slow it down to conserve battery power? Is it better to stop / start it every time?

Comment: Set up a timer to start the location manager every 15 seconds. When the location manager updates (and has a satisfactory degree of accuracy), stop the location manager.

Comment: Well yes, i did think of doing that, i am just unsure if starting it consumes more then keeping it running

Comment: Consider setting the location manager's `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` property to YES. This might just solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue for one of my app. where i need to send user location to back end.
my trick to solve this problem.

1- i had first set a global location (two string for latitude & longitude) , initialized then at first launch of "didUpdateToLocation".

2- for the next time when didUpdateToLocation called , i had a check to see if its the  previous location or a new location. if new location then only update send to back end.

3- main trick was this

```
NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
 if (locationAge > 5.0) return;
```

its give me a time time interval when location update will be called.

here is the code (may be little bit old)

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

{

```
// test that the horizontal accuracy does not indicate an invalid measurement
if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0) return;
// test the age of the location measurement to determine if the measurement is cached
// in most cases you will not want to rely on cached measurements
NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
if (locationAge > 5.0) return;
// store all of the measurements, just so we can see what kind of data we might receive

NSString *tempLat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f", [newLocation coordinate].latitude];
NSString *tempLong = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f", [newLocation coordinate].longitude];

//NSLog(@"lat--%@\nlong--%@",tempLat,tempLong);
////check if location matches with currenlty saved location
if (![tempLat isEqualToString:self.latitude] && ![tempLong isEqualToString:self.longitude]) 
{
 //call to webservice  
}

}
```

hope it will help you!!!

Answer (score 0):

The location manager is going to fire, as it sees fit, whenever A)it gets a more accurate fix B)it sees movement beyond your distance filter setting. You can use `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` to enable it to quit looking when practical.

On your side, act responsibly. You should test every event, if it is too recent, inaccurate or has not changed enough to warrant reaction then ignore. Best case, you would stopUpdating and set to region monitoring or wake on significant location changes at that point. If you require continuous updates at all times, you are not going to have many options.